# How i can i iterate through data on website

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract users from a website bu using for loop, but i don't know how can i put correctly "i" instead of number 1

after i put

```
user_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+str(i)+"]").text
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Code/Python/Instagram
>   Unfollow/Instagram Unfollow.py", line 32, in 
>       user_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+str(i)+"]").text
>   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class='*gzjax'])[0]"}
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal* (file:///c:/users/viktor/appdata/local/temp/tmp1r0vgw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/viktor/appdata/local/temp/tmp1r0vgw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/viktor/appdata/local/temp/tmp1r0vgw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/viktor/appdata/local/temp/tmp1r0vgw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/viktor/appdata/local/temp/tmp1r0vgw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: can't you  concatenate the i var in  the xpath string e.g "(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+i+"]"

Comment: @user993553 i tried like this "+i+", but it gives error i guess i;m missing something

Comment: double check your code.  looks like the underscore is getting dropped:  this is in your error output:  {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class='gzjax'])[0]"}  so the concat is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate `i` (first cast it to string) to your desired string:

```
for i in range (0,100):
    user_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+str(i)+"]").text
    print(user_id)
```

Comment: @Viktor This is does not related to putting i as string in xpath , it means the element you looking for is not in page.

Comment: oh thanks i figure out, i needed to start loop from 1 not from 0.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I think you concatenate variables into string with plus sign in python:

```
user_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+i+"]").text
```

see how we add ("string" + variable + "string")

Comment: you can't concatenate strings and integers with a plus sign

Answer (score 0):

You would need to explicitly convert `i` from int to string. How about:

```
for i in range (0,100):
    user_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])["+str(i)+"]").text
    print(user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many users there are on the page, but as it stands you're bound to 101.

Could just loop through the elements?

```
for i in browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_gzjax'])"):
    user_id = i.text
    print(user_id)
```

Something along those lines where you are iterating over items instead of indices.